# How to create a Sql Statement from a mutable Json File using Java

Tags: java, sql, json, postgresql, openapi

I'm trying to create SQL Tables from a Json File which is written following the OpenApi Specification. Here is an example of an Input file I must convert:

```
     "definitions": {
"Order": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "integer",
      "format": "int64"
    },
    "petId": {
      "type": "integer",
      "format": "int64"
    },
    "quantity": {
      "type": "integer",
      "format": "int32"
    },
    "shipDate": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date-time"
    },
    "status": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Order Status",
      "enum": [
        "placed",
        "approved",
        "delivered"
      ]
    },
    "complete": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": false
    }
  },
  "xml": {
    "name": "Order"
  }
},
"Category": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "integer",
      "format": "int64"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "xml": {
    "name": "Category"
  }
},
```

My aim to to create two tables named "Order" and "Category" whose columns must be to ones listed in the "properties" field. I'm using Java.
The Input file is mutable, so I used Gson to read it. I managed to get an Output like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE ORDER
    COLUMNS:
    id->
    type: integer
    format: int64

    petId->
    type: integer
    format: int64

    quantity->
    type: integer
    format: int32

    shipDate->
    type: string
    format: date-time

    status->
    type: string
    description: Order Status
    Possibilities: 
    -placed
    -approved
    -delivered

    complete->
    type: boolean
    default: false

    CREATE TABLE CATEGORY
    COLUMNS:
    id->
    type: integer
    format: int64

    name->
    type: string
```

I'm stuck here, trying to convert the "type" and "format" fields into a type that can be read by PostgreSQL or MySQL. Furthermore, it is hard to work directly on the code to get a readable SQL string due the presence of nesting. So I thought it might be a good idea to work on the output and "translate" it to SQL. Is there any class\package that could help me reading a file like this? I'm trying to avoid the use of thousands IF ELSE conditions. Thank you.

Comment: Did you see http://blog.sqlizer.io/posts/convert-json-to-sql/?

Comment: So you are creating your tables on the fly based on the contents of a JSON? That does not seem to be the right path. I recommend you to get your openApi read all possible values, then create your database as such. Creating a database on the fly based on your JSon definitely isn't  a good approach. Consider either using a database that supports JSON objects (e.g. postgresql) or a nosql database that is purely json documents such as mongodb.

Comment: That's the point. My assignment is to give the program a Json Input, "press a button" and create a Sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment involves two phases.

One is "Parsing" the given JSON object and understanding the content

Second one is "Translating" the parsed content into a working SQL query

Here your Java program should work as a kind of Translation engine.

For parsing the JSON objects many java libraries are available. 
To translate the parsed json into a SQL query you can simply use basic String manipulation methods.